# AlarmReceiver Stay Awake (briefly)

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, wakelock

I have read 100s of SO and other articles. I cannot find an answer. Thanks in advance for the help.

Note: I save the major events in my app to sharedPreferences. This way I am able to record and "Playback" what happens when the phone goes to doze mode after the fact.

```
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Objective: Wake the phone from DOZE/SLEEP, call a few asynch http/rest APIs, collect a small amount of data, make a decision, go back to sleep.

Problem: Within one millisecond of AlarmReceiver being invoked from the alarm and calling MainActivity, MainActivity goes from OnCreate to OnResume, to OnStop, to OnDestroy. The http/rest calls never get called.

I use AlarmManager to wake the phone. This works, my log (above) proves it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverMainAct.class);
amPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, trdLocal.getAmIntentID(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trdLocal.getWakeTime(), amPendingIntent); // requires API 23+
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trdLocal.getWakeTime(), amPendingIntent);
```

I have an AlarmReceiver to catch the above AlarmManager action. The Alarm Receiver invokes MainActivity. This works, my log (above) proves it.

I tried placing a 3 minute expiring WakeLock in the AlarmReceiver. I also tried placing a 3 minute expiring WakeLock in MainActivity.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "AlarmActivity");
    mWakeLock.acquire(timeOut);
```

Will a WakeLock solve my problem? If not, what is the best approach to Wake the phone from DOZE/SLEEP, call a few asynch http/rest APIs, collect a small amount of data, make a decision, go back to sleep.

Comment: On which Android version are you testing this?

Comment: Android version 8.0.0

Comment: Android 8 introduced quite a few new restrictions on background services (check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#O . There are a number of ways to deal with this, but using PendingIntent and AlarmManager isn't the best way. Have a look at JobScheduler and JobIntentService

Comment: @Jeroen thanks. I am testing JobScheduler. It seems much easier to use given it handles wakeLocks, network etc. I am still investigating a test I ran last night with setPeriodic(waitTime). I set waitTime to 60 minutes at 7:30PM and unplugged the phone thinking it would wake up / fire every hour. The first wakeup was 9:21PM. The second was 11:16PM, the next at 3:11AM and that was it. Does setPeriodic(waitTime) not run the job every "waitTime" minutes?

Comment: I'm not sure, my experience with JobScheduler is fairly limited unfortunately